# Search for the existence of a dependency in a maven project

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

For part of a script I am building I would like to be able to search a maven project for a certain dependency. I have had a look at the `dependency` plugin for maven but I can't find any good tutorials on how to use it and have had no luck with using it so far.

What is the best way to search for the existence dependency in a maven project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing is to use [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html) itself like:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=velocity:velocity
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a big help!

Comment: Do you happen to know whether dependency:tree or dependency:list is a faster method for listing dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the maven dependency plugin in combination with a shell script. AFAIK the dependency plugin does not support searching for a particular artifact.

Here an example:

If you run `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:list`

an output could be similar to:

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
```

you will see a full list of your dependencies.

now if you run on a linux based system you could just simply write a bash script that checks if the dependency exists:

dependencyExists=`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:list | grep "org.hamcrest:hamcrest"`

if the variable is filled the dependency is there, otherwise not.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I am required to use create a Windows batch file, however a similar result can be achieved using 'findstr'.